# Is there a way to do auto exposure from a fixed point in Camera X?

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I am working on an app that requires me to set the exposure of the frame always from the centre of the preview image. I am working on CameraXin Android and I was wondering if there is a clean way of doing this?
P.s: Java Snippets are appreciated.
Thanks

Edit:

I have implemented a function for doing the same but because it's not activated by tap it's way harder to tell if my function is working correctly or is it normal autofocus and auto exposure.

The following is the code that I have implemented and because of the project restriction I am bound to use CameraX "1.0.0-alpha06" version:

```html
private void setUpTapToFocus(CameraControl cameraControl) {
        Log.v("Metering Point","inFunction");
        //Can't use sensorOrientedMeteringPointFactory because of CameraX version
        MeteringPointFactory factory = new SensorOrientedMeteringPointFactory(viewFinder.getWidth(),viewFinder.getHeight());
        int centerWidth = viewFinder.getWidth()/2;
        int centerHeight = viewFinder.getHeight()/2;
        MeteringPoint point = factory.createPoint(centerWidth,centerHeight);
        cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(FocusMeteringAction.Builder.from(point).
        .setAutoFocusCallback(isSuccess -> Log.v("SKAXC Point","Focused").
        .setAutoCancelDuration(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build());
}

onCreate(){
        CameraControl cameraControl = CameraX.getCameraControl(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK);
        setUpTapToFocus(cameraControl);
}
```

Comment: What are you using for preview? If you're using `PreviewView`, you can use its MeteringPointFactory to create a metering point at the center of the preview, build a metering action where you pass in the metering point and the metering mode, which in your case would be `FLAG_AE`, then use the camera control to trigger the metering action.

Comment: May I know what is auto exposure. Is it focusing or flashlight ?

Comment: @VikasAcharya It's Auto Exposure and Auto Whitebalance.
Flag_AE and Flag AWB as mentioned in the following link
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/FocusMeteringAction

Comment: @HusaynHakeem
I have implemented a similar function. But I can't confirm if it's working and I want to know if the code is correct:
https://gist.github.com/doomSDey/a6b553665680b3b1d19aaeba522c5664